# Should a paver patio slope in the direction of yard grade?

Tags: patio, pavers

I recently went with a contractor to get pavers installed. They are working on the patio and this is a photo of the installation that I took today. The contractor said that since my yard is higher on the right side, they decided to have the pavers drain towards that side as well. The uneven line by the house is concerning me. Is this reasonable?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean draining to the left?

Comment: I mean yea, you don't drain to the higher side, that results in pooling.

Comment: Is it just the photo? It seems to be not -level _front to back_ which would *not* be correct.  Put a six-foot level or laser level where you take the photo perpendicular to the house and that *should* be nearly perfectly level. The plane of slope is [or should be]  parallel to the house.

Comment: What is that line of buff colour near to the house? Is that a drain? Are there any proper drains? If there are, then the area should slope towards that. If not, then it should slope away from the house.

Answer (score 8):

You can slope pavers, yes, to avoid water settling, especially if you have drainage issues at the site. And sloping is not level, so it will be different from your house, which is level. Looks good to me.

Added: as a rule, if the current grade is not leading to pooled water, you keep it sloping the way it is.

Comment: You _should_ slope pavers.

Comment: @SteveWellens, that's debatable. Pavers are permeable, so in many cases there's no good reason to put slope in a structure that's ideally level. It depends on what's adjacent.

Comment: The word I used is _should_, not _must_.   Perhaps you don't live in a climate where standing water can freeze and turn to ice.   Ice that a senior citizen can slip on, break a hip, and spend the rest of their time on earth bed ridden and in agony.  You may feel different, but I think that is wrong.

Comment: @isherwood most (admittedly, not all) patios are adjacent to a home, which is definitely something you want to slope to drain away from.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be inquiring about aesthetics more than anything.

Yes, I would have requested that the contractor either dig down the right side or raise the left side so that it's level. This ***should*** have been specified before the work was started.

Then, apply a very gentle slope away from the house into your lawn.

As long as they haven't sloped anything towards your foundation then you should be structurally fine but I do dislike the unevenness shown by your picture.

---

Applying a fix now would mean removing at least half of the pavers and doing some leveling work.

Did you neglect to specify this detail? Did they neglect to have you think about this detail? Are they not installing to spec? The blame-game is not going to be fun.

You might have to pay for a change order or they might have to eat the cost to fix this situation. It all goes back to what was agreed in the beginning. They haven't done anything structurally egregious based on your pictures.

Answer (score 1):

The only question is whether there should be *two* slopes.  You definitely need one slope that drains *away* from the house.  Whether or not you need a slope along the house wall is debatable.  I'd argue it's not necessary, but it can depend on your yard grading.  You don't want to end up with a dropoff at the side of your patio.

Answer (score 1):

This looks good to me.

Unless you stated in your contract with the contractor that you wanted it level, and paid extra for it, the slope is going to match the slope of your land. Leveling things takes a lot of time/work.